# Getting the parse tree for a predefined function in R

Tags: r, substitution, parse-tree

I feel as if this is a fairly basic question, but I can't figure it out.

If I define a function in R, how do I later use the name of the function to get its parse tree. I can't just use `substitute` as that will just return the parse tree of its argument, in this case just the function name.

For example,

```
> f <- function(x){ x^2 }
> substitute(f)
f
```

How should I access the parse tree of the function using its name? For example, how would I get the value of `substitute(function(x){ x^2 })` without explicitly writing out the whole function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure which of these meets your desires:

```
 eval(f)
#function(x){ x^2 }

 identical(eval(f), get("f"))
#[1] TRUE
 identical(eval(f), substitute( function(x){ x^2 })  )
#[1] FALSE

 deparse(f)
#[1] "function (x) " "{"             "    x^2"       "}"            

 body(f)
#------
{
    x^2
}
#---------

eval(parse(text=deparse(f)))
#---------
function (x) 
{
    x^2
}
#-----------

 parse(text=deparse(f))
#--------
expression(function (x) 
{
    x^2
})
#--------

 get("f")
# function(x){ x^2 }
```

The print representation may not display the full features of the values  returned.

```
 class(substitute(function(x){ x^2 }) )
#[1] "call"
 class( eval(f) ) 
#[1] "function"
```

Comment: I might be missing smth, but I don't think any of those expressions achieves what the OP wants, i.e. same output as `substitute(function(x){ x^2 })`

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to yours. After a bit more playing around with the list of functions, `parse(text = deparse(f))[[1]]` is exactly the same as using `substitute` with the fully written out function.

Answer (score 3):

The function `substitute` can substitute in values bound to an environment. The odd thing is that its `env` argument does not possess a default value, but it defaults to the evaluation environment. This behavior seems to make it fail  when the evaluation environment is the global environment, but works fine otherwise.

Here is an example:

```
> a = new.env()
> a$f = function(x){x^2}
> substitute(f, a)
function(x){x^2}
> f = function(x){x^2}
> environment()
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> substitute(f, environment())
f
> substitute(f, globalenv())
f
```

As demonstrated, when using the global environment as the second argument the functionality fails.

A further demosntration that it works correctly using `a` but not the global environment:

```
> evalq(substitute(f), a)
function(x){x^2}
> evalq(substitute(f), environment())
f
```

Quite puzzling.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently that's indeed some weird quirk of `substitute` and is mentioned [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b8b7a8f8beabb51642764b2aa9f209417a42edcd/src/main/coerce.c#L2453):

> /*    do_substitute has two arguments, an expression and an
>   environment    (optional).    Symbols found in the expression are
>   substituted with their    values as found in the environment. There is
>   no inheritance so only    the supplied environment is searched. If no
>   environment is specified    the environment in which substitute was
>   called is used.  **If the    specified environment is R_GlobalEnv it is
>   converted to R_NilValue, for    historical reasons.** In substitute(),
>   R_NilValue signals that no    substitution should be done, only
>   extraction of promise expressions.    Arguments to do_substitute
>   should not be evaluated.
>   */

And you have already found a way of circumventing it:

```
e = new.env()
e$fn = f
substitute(fn, e)
```

Comment: Actually, upon further testing it appears this doesn't quite work. The type of `substitute(f, a)` is a closure, whereas the type of 'substitute(function(x){ x^2 })' is a language object, specifically a call. The difference is quite important as a closure is not subsettable, but a call is. Do you know any quick way to convert from a closure to a call? `as.call` will not work.

Comment: good point, btw I just realized that `as.list(f)` does essentially the same thing as `substitute` would