# Resuming stopped evaluation in R with correct search path

Tags: r, environment-variables, substitution

I have a function within a loaded library that stops the evaluation on its arguments using the substitute function. This function then calls another within that same library, which calls another function from that library, and so forth, until several calls later when I want to evaluated that initial argument in the *original* environment in which it was provided. The problem I have is that the search path for functions in loaded libraries includes `namespace::base` before the global environment. For example, let's say that `foo` and `bar` are both functions in the library `lib`. As such, the environment in which they are defined is `namespace::lib`. Consider the following:

```
> require(lib)
> foo
function (x) 
{
    x <- substitute(x)
    bar(x)
}
<environment: namespace:lib>
> bar
function (x) 
{
     eval(x)
}
<environment: namespace:lib>
> length = 2
> foo(length)
function (x)  .Primitive("length")
```

Because `bar` is a function within a loaded library, it searches `namespace::base` first and finds the above. However, if `bar` was defined by the user in the interactive session, it would have returned `2`. I am looking for a way to cause these functions to behave as if I never halted evaluation, in which case `2` would be returned regardless of the environment in which the functions are defined.

I can't simply use `mget` to evaluate `length` starting at `.GlobalEnv` because then the following would not work:

```
> baz = function()
+ {
+ length <- 3
+ foo(length)
+ }
> baz()
function (x)  .Primitive("length")
```

I could instead add an extra argument to all involved functions that tracks how many frames ago the evaluation was halted. However, this is pretty messy and not ideal.

I could also call `sys.function` inside the last function, `bar`, and trace my way back through the previous calls and evaluate my argument in the environment above the function that halted the evaluation. For example, if I call `sys.function(1)` within the body of `bar` after calling `foo(length)` then I get the following:

```
function (x) 
{
    eval(x)
}
```

This is indeed identical to `foo`. I can then use `eval` with `sys.frames`. This seems more general but less than perfect. I would have to know which functions stop evaluation.

Does anyone have a more general solution?

Comment: `substitute` takes an `env` argument.

Comment: Having that argument set to the global environment behaves weirdly and no variable substitution is done. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17223365/2019846

Answer (score 0):

Does adding a default enviroment to these function help with the problem?

```
lib<-new.env()
assign("foo", function(x, env=parent.frame()) {
    x<-substitute(x); 
    bar(x, env)
}, envir=lib)
assign("bar", function(x, env=parent.frame()) {
    eval(x, env)
}, envir=lib)
attach(lib)

length = 2
foo(length)
# [1] 2

baz <- function() {
  length <- 3
  foo(length)
}
baz()
# [1] 3

bar(expression(baz()))
# [1] 3
```

If not, perhaps you could make a clearer, reproducible example with function calls and your expected output. Otherwise it's unclear where you are having trouble.